# Can a Single Page Application built for Web be used for building a PWA using react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am somewhat new to the concept of building a Progressive Web Application (PWA). I am a little confused regarding this. I have built a React Application for Web. Can I use the same project for building its PWA or do I need to create a separate project (using create-react-app) for that?

If I can use the same project then how will I design the structure of the App for the mobile screen (using CSS media queries)?

Comment: Yes, you can. A PWA is just an interpreted web app you can turn your standard react app in to a PWA. Use a `manifest.json` file in the public folder to control how your app appears to the user and define its appearance at launch.

Comment: There are references available such as https://github.com/Kay2dan/react-pwa-guide-kit and that on mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps

Comment: i think converting that to perfect PWA is difficult. Use ionic react with capacitor can help

Comment: Thanks, guys for answering this!!!
I have a question...I am already using Semantic-ui-react in my project. Would it be suitable to use Ionic React along with it?